# Can I get verbose output from screen?

Tags: command-line, screen, console

I am trying to get my PC connected to a remote PC using a serial FTDI connectors I run the command:

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

but nothing happens, it just seems to lock up the console. Is there a verbose option for the screen command? is there any way I can see more of what is, or is not happening?

The Tutorial I am following is Here:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/test-and-configure

Comment: The tutorial is in error. The parameter you're passing to `screen` is the _command_ to execute `/dev/tty/USB0` is not a command.

Comment: ok, so should I pass screen something like: /dev/ttyUSB0 login?

Answer (score 1):

[`man screen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/screen.1.html) lists this command-line option:

```
-L   tells screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows.
```

Running `screen -L [ cmd [ args ] ]` enables automatic logging.